# How to pass a html template through props to a react component?

Tags: html, reactjs

I have a popup up window react component.  I want to pass in templates to the component via props.

Here is an example of my popup

```
popup = (
   <div>
     <Popup text='This is a popup'
            popupEl={ popupEl }
     />
   </div>
);
```

The popup component works if the popupElements value is a button on its own, or a list of checkboxes.  But I want to pass in an entire template.  Unfortunately the popupElements prop is seen as undefined when I try to do so.

Here is a very basic example of a template I want to pass in.  Is there something I'm missing here?

```
popupEl = (
   <div>
      <div>
        <h1> hi </h1>
      </div>
      <div>
        <button>CLOSE</button>
      </div>
   </div>
);
```

Comment: You could try actually passing it, like as an argument...

Comment: @DaveNewton  I would do that, but it doesn't make the popup component flexible, I would then need to hardcode in elements within the component for any speciic prop passed in..

Comment: What's the difference between expecting it to be available via a global variable and passing it in as a parameter? (Other than the latter is a better idea, I mean.)

Comment: Is there a way to keep the component flexible with the way you suggested?

Comment: Either use normal ReactJS `{props.children}` or pass in whatever it is you want to render? It's not clear what the issue really is.

Comment: Define `undefined`.

Comment: > Unfortunately the popupElements prop is seen as undefined when I try to do so.

can you show this code? it's not clear where or why its undefined

Comment: @azium I use react tools to look at the contents of my <Popup> props.  If popupElements contains only a button, it will pass in fine.  But if is equal to the template shown above, it is seen as undefined.

Comment: can you show us the entire relevant code? it sounds like you're just defining `popupElements` after `popup`. it's not `undefined` just because it's more than a button

Comment: alright I'll edit more code in

Comment: Note also that stateless components should be functions, not expressions.

Comment: alright I updated to show popup component

Comment: Looks like I found the problem, @azium you were right, it really was that popupElements was defined after popup

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The popupEl should be a function which returns JSX,

```
popupEl = () =>
   <div>
      <div>
        <h1> hi </h1>
      </div>
      <div>
        <button>CLOSE</button>
      </div>
   </div>
);
```